# procedure Free() of the base class is never called in Generics

Tags: delphi, generics

In my code, the `Free()` method of the `TFirst` class is never invoked when I call the `ReleaseInstance()` method. Would it be possible to get around this **without forcing a `TFirst` cast?** I tried using RTTI, but was unsuccessful.

This works, but it doesn't use Generics correctly:

```
TFirst(Self.FInstance).Free;
```

Any suggestion is welcome, thank you.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TSingleton<T: class, constructor> = class
  strict private
    class var FInstance: T;
  public
    class function GetInstance: T;
    class procedure ReleaseInstance;
  end;

type
  TFirst = class
  public
    procedure Free;
  end;

type
  TSecond = class(TFirst)
  end;

type
  TMySingleton = TSingleton<TSecond>;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TSingleton<T> }

class function TSingleton<T>.GetInstance: T;
begin
  if not Assigned(Self.FInstance) then
    Self.FInstance := T.Create;

  Result := Self.FInstance;
end;

class procedure TSingleton<T>.ReleaseInstance;
begin
  if Assigned(Self.FInstance) then
    FreeAndNil(T(TClass(Self.FInstance)));
end;


{ TFirst }

procedure TFirst.Free;
begin
  // It's not called
  inherited Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   TMySingleton.GetInstance;
   TMySingleton.ReleaseInstance;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 10):

Your `TFirst.Free()` method hides the inherited `TObject.Free()` method, which is not `virtual` so descendants can't override it.

You don't need your `TFirst.Free()` method at all, you should be overriding the virtual `Destroy()` destructor instead, which `TObject.Free()` (and thus `FreeAndNil()`) calls for you:

```
type
  TFirst = class
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

destructor TFirst.Destroy;
begin
  // ...
  inherited Destroy;
end;
```

Also, the statement:

```
FreeAndNil(T(TClass(Self.FInstance)));
```

It both overly verbose and just plain wrong, as you are type-casting an object pointer into a class type. It should simple be this instead:

```
FreeAndNil(Self.FInstance);
```

Since `FInstance` is an object pointer, and `FreeAndNil()` frees objects.

Also, you don't need to check `Assigned()` before using `FreeAndNil()` (or `TObject.Free()`) since it handles that internally for you.  So, `ReleaseInstance()` can simply be this instead:

```
class procedure TSingleton<T>.ReleaseInstance;
begin
  FreeAndNil(Self.FInstance);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you @Remy for your answer, as you detailed, I can't use override in Free because it is not virtual in the base class (TObject), calling FreeAndNil(Self.FInstance); it does not call the Free method of the TFirst class, but I need the flow to go through the Free method of the TFirst class, this is mandatory as it is declared.

Comment: @WesleyBobato "*calling FreeAndNil(Self.FInstance); it does not call the Free method of the TFirst class*" - it is not supposed to, because it calls `TObject.Free` instead. "*I need the flow to go through the Free method of the TFirst class*" - then you can't use `FreeAndNil()`, you'll have to call `TFirst.Free` directly, eg: `Self.FInstance.Free; Self.FInstance := nil;` Otherwise, change your design as I described in my answer. "*this is mandatory as it is declared*" - it's a bad/incorrect design, IMHO

Comment: @WesleyBobato Don't complain about your wrong class design not working, fix it as Remy described it, then it will work as intented!